# Passing data between two instantiated WinForms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Main Form which dows calculations and opens and closes projects created by a user.

When the user clicks on the Open Project button under File, a form called Open Project opens as below which allows a user to load a project:

[image]

Now, I want to pass the data from this form into the main form after clicking OK.

The problem I am having is that the Main Form is already open.

Any solution to this problem would be hghly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how you think that the Main Form already being open is a problem. Why can't you simply have the main form get whatever information you want from the other forms? Sounds like you need a property in your other form class(es).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a `Properties` in `Open Project Form`

**Main Form**

```
private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var f = new Open_Project_Form())
    {
      f.ProjectReference = projectRefrencetTextBox.Text;
      f.ProjectNo = projectNoTextBox.Text;
      f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Open Project Form**

```
public string ProjectReference { get; set; }
public string ProjectNo { get; set; }

private void Open_Project_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    projectRefrenceComboBox.Text = ProjectReference;
    projectNoTextBox.Text = ProjectReference;
}
```

---

## UPDATE

I misinterpreted the question. My previous answer is from `MainForm` to `OpenProjectForm` this time is from `OpenProjectForm` to `MainForm`

**Main Form**

```
//Properties for MainForm
public string ProjectReference { get; set; }
public string ProjectNo { get; set; }

private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var f = new Open_Project_Form() { Owner = this })
    {
        f.ShowDialog();
        if (f.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          projectRefrencetTextBox.Text = ProjectReference;
          projectNoTextBox.Text = ProjectNo;
        }
    }
}
```

**Open Project Form:** Take note that you have a `okButton` and `cancelButton`

```
private void Open_Project_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    okButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.AcceptButton = okButton;
    this.CancelButton = cancelButton;
}
```

Now, in `okButton_Click event`

```
private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var f = Owner as MainForm;
   if (f == null) return;
   f.ProjectReference = projectRefrenceComboBox.Text;
   f.ProjectNo = projectNoTextBox.Text;
   Close();
}
```

Reference:

- [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx)
- [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx)
- [Button.DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx)

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: I've just tested this and it works perfectly! Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Events? Create an EventClass and Return the value as Result of the Event.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in the opened form class:

```
public event EventHandler<ProjectDetailsArgs> ProjectDetailsSubmitted;
    public class ProjectDetails: EventArgs
    {
        public string projectReference{ get; set; }
        public string projectNo{get;set;}
        //you can add more prop.s here
    }

On your Ok button click event add 

if (ProjectDetailsSubmitted != null)
                {
                    ProjectDetailsArgs argss = new ProjectDetailsArgs();
                    argss.projectReference = projectRefrencetTextBox.Text;
                    argss.projectNo = projectNoTextBox.Text;
                    ProjectDetailsSubmitted(null, argss);
                }
```

In your main form create a handler for it:

```
  childform.ProjectDetailsSubmitted+=new EventHandler<ProjectDetailsArgs>project_detailsSubmitted);

                public void project_detailsSubmitted(object sender, ProjectDetailsArgs e)
                {
         //Do Your work
                }
```