# How to change the WPF window's lable text from another wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one Page Call Page 1 and on page one there are  1 Controls
 - label 
 - Button

On click on button I am going to open new Wpf window and in that There is a button and on that  button's click i want to change the 1st window label text.

```
LobbyStandardPopupView objLobbyStandardPopupView = new LobbyStandardPopupView();
objLobbyStandardPopupView.Show();

LobbyStandardView objLobbyStandardView = new LobbyStandardView();
objLobbyStandardView.Ring_Game.Text = "Hello";
```

I try  to created the object and change the control value but its not effected.

Comment: it may not be making the changes but is in the windows process queue. Application.DoEvents() to see the changes. This is just a suggestion as I have not seen any code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788077/passing-data-between-two-instantiated-winforms-in-c-sharp/14788266#14788266

Comment: Simple calling wpf window form . with opendialog()

Comment: Try to set the Owner property of your wpf window, so you can have a reference of your calling page into your called window

Comment: michele how can i set ? My code is LobbyStandardPopupView objLobbyStandardPopupView = new LobbyStandardPopupView();    objLobbyStandardPopupView.Show();    LobbyStandardView objLobbyStandardView = new LobbyStandardView();  objLobbyStandardView.Ring_Game.Text = "Hello";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your calling window:

```
ChildWindow w = new ChildWindow ();
w.Owner = this; //here your calling window
w.Show();
```

On your child window:

```
(this.Owner as YourMainWindow).YourProperty  = "Your Text";
```

the Owner property is a Window, so if you want to access a your custom property you have to cast to your window type.

In your case, using a Page, add this proprerty to your `LobbyStandardPopupView`:

```
 public LobbyStandardView mycallingpage = null;
 public LobbyStandardPopupView(LobbyStandardView callingPage)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     mycallingpage = callingPage;
 }
```

and in your button event:

```
mycallingpage.Ring_Game.Text = "Hello";
```

Comment: Thanks for your important reply but i am getting this error Error 9 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClientApplication.View.LobbyStandardView' to 'System.Windows.Window'

Comment: the Owner property is a Window. So you have to set it to a Window. LobbyStandardView object is a Page? Eventually in your Popup object create a property where you store a reference to your calling Page, something you call OwnerPage for example.

Comment: On my Parent  page  button click  :-   LobbyStandardPopupView objLobbyStandardPopupView = new LobbyStandardPopupView();                         objLobbyStandardPopupView.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
            objLobbyStandardPopupView.Show();    now on my child button click ...  ((LobbyStandardView)this.Owner as  LobbyStandardView ).Ring_Game.Text = "Your Text";    but give me cas t error

Comment: Because Window.GetWindow(this) will return a Window not a LobbyStandardView. I'll update my answer, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: @ujjaval I've updated my answer. If the problem is solved, please consider to accept the answer.