# Accessing Controls Globaly Through A Variable

Tags: c#

I have got two forms, both with a text box, which when a string is inputed, the rich text box displays it. I want to be able to make a class or some reference in which I can define a variable 'text' and set it equal to the input 'textBox1.Text'. When a user inputs anything into the textbox, I want to store that as a variable, and display it on the other screen. If am able to do this, can you show me, its really frustating!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [Passing data between two instantiated WinForms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788077/passing-data-between-two-instantiated-winforms-in-c-sharp/14788132#14788132)

But in your case, just create a `static class` let say

```
public class static Setter
{
   //Properties
   public static string set1{ get; set; }
   public static string set2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use like

```
string test = "test";
Setter.set1 = test;
```